# How to  use more than one custom labels with Core Plot?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

I am having an issue with core plot which is causing me grief and having scoured the internet cannot find a solution.  I fear it is a very simple oversight but for the life of me I cannot work out what it is.

Essentially when I set custom labels in core plot, only one of the labels appears at tick location zero, even though the relevant arrays are populated with the correct data like tick location and label.

I by-passed the custom label routine by manually entering in newLabels into the customLabels array and this worked, so I fear I am missing something basic in the routine somewhere.

```
NSUInteger labelLocation = 0;
NSMutableArray *customLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.days count]];


for (NSNumber *tickLocation in self.customTickLocations)
{

    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[self.dateLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation] textStyle:axisTextStyle];
newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
    int i = [tickLocation intValue];

    newLabel.offset = 5.0f;
    newLabel.rotation = M_PI/4;

    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
    NSLog(@"Label is %@", [self.dateLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation]);

    labelLocation = labelLocation + 1;


    NSLog(@"Tick Location is %i", i);
}
NSLog(@"Number of labels is %i", [customLabels count]);

axisSet.xAxis.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:self.customTickLocations];

NSLog(@"I have set customlabels");
```

This is my Log:

> 2012-09-11 10:39:23.725 SnoozeBaby[12000:c07] Label is 11 Sep
>
> 2012-09-11 10:39:23.725 SnoozeBaby[12000:c07] Tick Location is 0
>
> 2012-09-11 10:39:23.725 SnoozeBaby[12000:c07] Label is 10 Sep
>
> 2012-09-11 10:39:23.726 SnoozeBaby[12000:c07] Tick Location is 150
>
> 2012-09-11 10:39:23.726 SnoozeBaby[12000:c07] Number of labels is 2
>
> 2012-09-11 10:39:23.728 SnoozeBaby[12000:c07] I have set customlabels

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the `CPTAxis` labeling policy to `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone`?. Unless you do this you won't be able to see the labels.

Second thing to note is that you are not releasing each of the `CPTAxisLabel` object you are creating per iteration.

I haven't tested this but I would say that you should first set the location then the labels:

```
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:self.customTickLocations];
axisSet.xAxis.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
```

Comment: Many thanks El Developer.  I did have CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone, and I should have shown more code in hindsight.  My issue turned out to be that I was setting an xMax range for the plotSpace.XRange using a CGFloat variable but passing [fetchResults count] which is of course an int so xMax was setting itself zero.  I missed it because the compiler wasn't throwing up a warning.  Thanks for taking the time to help out though!